# Can i reference external assets from res folder?

Tags: android, android-resources

Beginner android developer here so please take it easy.

Is there a way to have the xml files in the res folder of a packaged apk access external files?

I'd like to be able to update assets on a server and update them by having the app download and replace those external assets.

The kicker is though, I don't want to have to use code in my app to pull the external assets, I'd like the app to automatically use them by having the res files point to those external assets. Does this make any sense at all? And if so is it even possible? (i need this functionality because other apps might use my apk for themeing purposes so i want those other apps to be pulling the external assets and not the ones packaged with the apk)

Comment: I'd highly suspect there's no way to use network resources as res/ file replacements. You will probably have to do this in code.

Comment: This is what I kind of figured from the research I've been doing, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the asset file by updating the app with newer assets. Apart from that I see no other option. Conversely you can copy initial data from assets to your private app directory during first run and update them as and when needed.

Comment: Ok, that's what I figured from the research I've been doing, thanks!